# Seeing an error when trying to create a new contact record

Tags: gack

I'm pretty new to resolving Salesforce issues. Currently in my org, no one is able to create a new contact record. The following error message is thrown. I submitted a case with Salesforce support team. Can anyone please help me out?

An internal server error has occurred
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!

Error ID: 1687564625-37431 (-631911389)

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic backend error from Salesforce, so it can't be debugged very easily.  I'd recommend undoing anything that was done recently.  For example, if you added a process builder, workflow rule, or even a formula field right before the issue started, I'd remove that and see if the error goes away.

I've only seen these a few times, but they were usually a cross-object formula or process builder with an unexpected value.

IE: you added a date calculation field, but some Contacts have values that result in negative dates or something.

If you aren't sure what changed recently, check the Setup Audit Trail.  Good luck!